# Exceeding SQL Server SP call nesting level of 32

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I came accross a business case where I need nested SP calls beyond the level of 32, which is the SQL Server's limit. Can anybody say whether there is a possibility to increase this limit?

Comment: I suggest, its time to review your business case implementation and choose a new one that does not violate the scope of technology used.

Answer (score 4):

No, 32 is the limit: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

[Nesting Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607.aspx)

32 is a deep call stack; I've never hit this limit before. It suggests you should look for an alternative approach.

Comment: +1. I hardly see call stacks deeper than 3-4 in SQL. That said some people seem to think sql server is an application server. I had people having slow sql stored procedures... thanks to external web service calls for every row ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you hit this limit, then you should be using udfs or CTEs for your recursive code. If it isn't recursive, it's really poor design.

I've never been more than about 4 deep including a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Recursive calling COULD be a really nice feature, especially when your output is XML and you need to get XML child nodes that are equal in format as the parent. The workaround is using stored procedures to handle the parent/child relationship, with the drawback of more complicated/redundant code. Say you have:

```
create table Users (UserID int, Name nvarchar(50), ManagerID int null)
insert into Users (1, 'Carl', null)
insert into Users (2, 'Tom', 1)
insert into Users (3, 'John', 1)
```

and

```
create function GetUser(@UserID int)
returns XML as
begin
    declare @xml XML
    SET @xml = (
        SELECT [UserID] "User/@UserID"
            , [Name] "User/@Name"
            FROM Users
            WHERE [UserID] = @UserID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )
    return @xml
end
```

To get all managers in an XML:

```
create proc GetAllManagers() as
begin
    set nocount on;
    SELECT dbo.GetUser([UserID]) 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE [ManagerID] IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, root('Managers')
end
```

Now to the problem. What if for each manager, I want all the users belonging to the manager? I would like my function to be able to call itself:

```
alter function GetUser(@UserID int, @IsIncludeChildren bit)
returns XML as
begin
    declare @xml XML
    SET @xml = (
        SELECT [UserID] "User/@UserID"
            , [Name] "User/@Name"
            , (SELECT dbo.GetUser([UserID], 0)) "User/Children"
            FROM Users
            WHERE [ManagerID] = @UserID AND @IsIncludeChildren = 1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )
    return @xml
end
```

and calling this simply

```
alter proc GetAllManagers() as
begin
    set nocount on;
    SELECT dbo.GetUser([UserID], 1) 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE [ManagerID] IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, root('Managers')
end
```

But this is not possible because of the nesting limit. So workaround is (using the first function):

```
alter proc GetAllManagers() as
begin
    set nocount on;
    SELECT 
      dbo.GetUser([UserID]) 
    , (
      SELECT dbo.GetUser([UserID])
          FROM Users 
          WHERE [ManagerID] = [Users].[UserID]
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) "User/Children"

    FROM Users as [Users]
    WHERE [ManagerID] IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, root('Managers')
end
```

This is not too bad, but if you have lots of other procedures returning user data, you will have to build the parent/child relationship in all procs, instead of in a single function!

So there, Microsoft, fix it!